# Deep understanding: How code structure affects the content of date arrays created with loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date

**Background explanation**

I have asked a question concerning defining an date array using a loop.

The array is defined on basis of a declared variable named "dateinterval". The way I designed the code resulted in an error message in relation to another loop and another user provided another loop for me which solved this.

Now that I have closely compared the two different solutions I simply do not understand why they do not produce the same outcome.

**My code**

I developed the below code to define an array of dates in UTC format. However the outcome is an array of dates in millisecs since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00. So in other words a number.

```
for (var i=0; i < difference; i++){
    dateinterval[dateinterval.length] = dateinterval[0].setDate(datointerval[0].getDate() + i);
};
```

**The proper solution**

The below code is the proper one provided to me by another user (thank you again!) This code defines an array of UTC dates.

```
for (var i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
    var dt = new Date(dateinterval[0]);
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + i);
    dateinterval[dateinterval.length] = dt;
};
```

**What I don't understand**

I have almost become blind from staring at the two different solutions to figure out what the difference is and I just don't get it.

To my untrained eyes it seems that the two pieces of code perform exactly the same operation and that the only difference is how they are structured. I have been informed that `setDate` returns millisecs and that in my code these millisecs were assigned to the array. But in the proper solution the variable `DT` is also assigned a `setDate` value which - as I understand it - should also be in millisecs. So why does the line:

```
dateinterval[dateinterval.length] = dt;
```

not assign millisecs to the dateinterval array?

Can anyone explain this to me so that I can better *understand* Javascript and not just replicate working solutions?

Comment: The return value from [*setDate*](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date.prototype.setdate) is the *timeclip*, i.e. the Date's internal time value, which is milliseconds since the epoch (1 January, 1970).

Comment: In other words, the first version assigns the return value of `Date.setDate()` to the variable. The second version assigns the date object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
dateinterval[dateinterval.length] = dateinterval[0].setDate(datointerval[0].getDate() + i);
```

you are assigning the return value of `dateinterval[0].setDate(…)` to `dateinterval[…]`. That return value is the [*timeclip*](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-timeclip) or internal timevalue of the Date object (which is milliseconds since 1 January, 1970). See [*ECMA-262 §20.3.4.20*](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date.prototype.setdate).

So you need to modify the Date first:

```
dateinterval[0].setDate(datointerval[0].getDate() + i);
```

then assign a reference to the object:

```
dateinterval[dateinterval.length] = dateinterval[0];
```

#### Edit

It may help to see a simple case.

```
// Create a new Date for 2015-01-01
var date = new Date(2015,0,1);

// Change the date to 2015-01-02
var x    = date.setDate(2);

// The return value from the method is the internal timevalue
console.log(x);

// Check the timevalue
console.log(new Date(x)); // 2 January, 2015
```

The OP seems to expect that *setDate* returns the original *Date* object, but it doesn't, it returns the *timevalue*. The original function will work if the return value from *setDate* is converted to a Date:

```
dateinterval[dateinterval.length] = new Date(dateinterval[0].setDate(datointerval[0].getDate() + i));
```

however that throws away the original Date object and creates a new one.

Comment: Thank you RobG for a fast answer. One thing I still don't understand though is how: `dateinterval[0].setDate(datointerval[0].getDate() + i);` _modifies_ the Date?

Comment: I am approving the answer as it seems to be the correct one. But the little grey cells in my head still have trouble wrapping themselves around it .... :o) All I can get out of this is that splitting up the operation into several `expressions` in stead of gathering it in one `expression` seems to produce the desired result. My brain tells me that is illogical - but then again it is also totally new to Javascript ...

Comment: @David If it helps you think about the problem any better, you expected the `setDate` method to support [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), but it does not. *Method chaining* is the pattern where a setter method returns the object on which the method is being called. For example, jQuery's setter methods use this pattern: `$("div").text("foo").addClass("bar").hide()`. Each setter (`text`, `addClass`) returns the original `$("div")` object. The `Date` object's `setDate` method does *not* support method chaining, so you cannot use that pattern here.

Comment: @apsillers thank you. It actually did help even though my conclusion also to some extent is that I am in above my head on this one. Need to understand more of the basics to fully understand the concept. But after reading more about `objects`, `arrays` and `method chaining` my understanding is this: the statement `variable = object.setDate` results in a `variable` with a `Date object` (the modification @RobG is talking about). My code contains a `statement` which due to lack of support for method chaining ends up assigning a number in stead of a Date object to the array.  Thank you all.